# Как можно получить прогресс загрузки отправляемого файла через QTcpSocket?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcpsocket

Я оправляю файл по сокету сервер->клиенту:

```
 while (1) {
                       QByteArray b = file.read(8192);
                       if (b.isEmpty()) {
                           pClientSocket->flush();
                           break;
                       }
                      // stream <b;
                       pClientSocket->write(b);
                       writingBytes0 += b.size();
                       if(isvisible)
/*Эта строка отправляет прогрес в диалог*/ emit siupdprogrint(writingBytes0);

                    }
```

Прогресс бар отобразит только прогресс записаного файла в сокет, но я хочу чтобы он показывал прогресс записанного файла на клиенте. Буду пробовать делать запись прогресса в сокет на стороне клиента и отсылать серверу, не  знаю получится или нет, но может есть способ получше, а может что то упускаю?

Comment: емнип, tcp байт-ориентированный протокол, не message-ориентированный, поэтому контроль за величиной передаваемого сообщения остается за протоколами более высокого уровня. Т.е. tcp-сокету неизвестен размер файла, он сам упакует-распакует, как ему нужно. Поэтому мне кажется наиболее правильным передавать в начале сообщения размер всех данных, а потом по ходу получения можно будет смотреть, сколько байт из анонсированных вы уже приняли из сокета.

Comment: Ну да я так делать и буду просто, просто я что хотел узнать, размер принятых данных нельзя ли посмотреть на стороне сервера или тут только клиент нужен. Я определяю размер данных записаных в сокет на сервере. Но клиент, то их еще в файл не записал а вот как узнать что он там записал, похоже токо ответные сообщ. для сервера с клиента кидать.  С принятием данных (отображением прогресса) проблем нету, но с отгрузкой.

Comment: мне кажется, т.к. сервер не отвечает за то, как данные будут использованы, он и не должен знать, все ли они записались в файл. Он же отвечает за передачу в сокет, даже не за прием, не то что за запись в файл. Если запись в файл не удалась, то это проблема клиента и ему переспрашивать у сервера файл или его часть, а передача-то удалась, сервер сделал свое дело.